# parse settext data to urlconnect

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

im having problems understanding how to parse data, i have a recycleview that get its text set from a companies array, when the user clicks on a card the companynumber of that card should be attached to the url for another query i just cant figure out how to do it thanks for any help

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    //companyList= new ArrayList<Company>();

    Company company = companies.get(i);
    viewHolder.textViewHead.setText(company.getCompanyTitle());
    viewHolder.textviewDesc.setText(company.getCompanyType());
    viewHolder.textViewNumber.setText(company.getCompanyNumber());
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ///send these to nodes them attach the officers, get both in nodes and send to myview
            Company company1 = companies.get(i);
            Intent skipintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Nodes.class);
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NAME, company1.getCompanyTitle());
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_TYPE, company1.getCompanyType());
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NUMBER, company1.getCompanyNumber());
            //  view.getContext().startActivity(skipintent);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(KEY_NAME, company1.getCompanyTitle());
            bundle.putString(KEY_TYPE, company1.getCompanyType());
            bundle.putString(KEY_NUMBER, company1.getCompanyNumber());
            skipintent.putExtras(bundle);
            new RetrieveFeedTask(//dont know what to put here).execute();


        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return companies.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textViewHead;
    private TextView textviewDesc;
    private TextView textViewNumber;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewhead);
        textviewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewDesc);
        textViewNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewNumber);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    }

}


    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
           ///here i want to put the texviewnumber
            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + textviewnumber +"/officers");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters to your asyncTask like this:

`new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(myStringArrayParameter);`

and in the asyncTask you can access is like this:

`URL url = new URL(API_URL + strings[0] +"/officers");`

your doInBackground() methods is look like this:

`doInBackground(String... strings)`

This means that you can add a String array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have problem to create url.

first, don't insert space.

and you don't get the textviewnumber text.

try

```
URL url = new URL(API_URL + textviewnumber.getText() +"/officers");
```

i hope you Work done.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the url is fine sadly I know it works its parsing the data over which isnt

Comment: which you tried input data into RetrieveFeedTask? 
try RetrieveFeedTask.execute(variable for use doInBackground);